# How to set the default value of the following struct field?

Tags: rust, builder

Here, `description` and `prompt` are optional, so their default value is `None`.

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Keymap {
    pub key: char,
    pub command: String,
    pub description: Option<String>,
    pub prompt: Option<String>,
}

impl Keymap {
    pub fn new<S: AsRef<str>>(key: char, command: S) -> Self {
        Self {
            key,
            command: command.as_ref().to_owned(),
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }

    pub fn with_prompt<S: AsRef<str>>(mut self, prompt: S) -> Self {
        self.prompt = Some(prompt.as_ref().to_owned());
        self
    }

    pub fn with_description<S: AsRef<str>>(mut self, description: S) -> Self {
        self.description = Some(description.as_ref().to_owned());
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let keymap = Keymap::new('a', "echo Hello, World!")
        .with_prompt("Enter your name:")
        .with_description("Prints 'Hello, World!'");

    println!("{:?}", keymap);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8d85f7baf2085282d6da48d93d565f0)

But I want `description`'s fallback value to be the value of `command`. If a `description` is provided, then that value should be used.

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want `description`'s default value to be the value of `command`.

```rust
impl Keymap {
    pub fn new<S: AsRef<str>>(key: char, command: S) -> Self {
        let command = command.as_ref().to_string();
        Self {
            key,
            description: Some(command.clone()),
            command,
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}
```

?

Not sure why `description` would still be an `Option` tho.

Alternatively, just fallback on the consumer side.

If you're asking if there's a way to make `description` magically be a copy of `command` unless it's explicitly set, then no. Though you could emulate that by keeping `description` private and accessing it via a method e.g.

```py
    pub fn description(&self) -> &str {
        self.description.as_deref().unwrap_or(&self.command)
    }
```

in which case you may want to impl `Debug` by hand.

Comment: `description` is an optional field. If you don't provide a description, the fallback is `command`'s value. I think `description` still has to be an `Option`?

Comment: If you're copying `command` to `description` upfront (in `new`) then no, `description` is either a copy of `command`, or it's a value explicitly set by `with_description`. There's no situation where it's unset. If you fallback at access time (e.g. via a `description()` method), then yes.

Comment: You're right, that makes sense.